# Remove Addthis Counter popup

Tags: addthis

What I am trying to do is to prevent the counter popup to show on click.If I try to remove the onclick event the counts don't show anymore.

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">

        <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
        <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>            
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by counter popup? In your case it's inline with other icons.

Comment: When you click on the addthis_counter a popup with multiple sharing links shows.That's what I'm trying to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#at20mc { display: none !important; }` in your css might work.

Comment: Yeap, my mistake. Fixed it for future reference.

Comment: make sure to place this code in style tag in your page right after addthis code snippet inclusion.

Comment: this trick doesn't work if you need the email sharing lightbox.

Answer (score 1):

This is configurable:

```
addthis_config.ui_show_promo = false
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're using the default style buttons (with the counter to the right-hand side), you can hide it by adding this to your CSS file:

```
.addthis_counter.addthis_pill_style.addthis_nonzero a.addthis_button_expanded {
    position: absolute !important;
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

The AddThis code inserts CSS with display: block !important; so I found this is the best way to get around that.

Answer (score 0):

go to plugin editor & just comment out the html line where class="addthis_counter"

```
<!-- <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>-->
```